# keep getting error : At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, derby

This is the code that i am executing.In this code i am trying to update ,y database with the details that i am getting from the combo boxes..

```
 private void SubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    Connection connection;
    try {
        int flag=1;
       try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.out.println("Error"+ex);
       }
        connection  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/loginDB", "login_user" ,"root");
        String query = "INSERT into FACULTY_DETAILS (FACULTYNAME,LECTUREQUALITY,COMSKILLS,KNOWLEDGE,BEHAVIOUR,NOTESPROVIDED,PUNCTUALITY,SUGGESTION) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        //Statement pt = connection.createStatement();
        pt.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet rs = pt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM LOGIN_USER.FACULTY_DETAILS");
        while(rs.next()){
        if(rs.getString(1).equals(kapil.getText())){
        pt.setString(2, (String) javalec.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(3,(String)javacomm.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(4,(String)javaknow.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(5, (String) javabeh.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(6, (String) javanot.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(7, (String) javapun.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(8,javatext.getText());
        pt.executeUpdate(); flag=0;}
         if(rs.getString(1).equals(ziaul.getText())){
        pt.setString(2, (String) oslec.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(3,(String)oscomm.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(4,(String)osknow.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(5, (String) osbeha.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(6, (String) osnote.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(7, (String) ospun.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(8,ostext.getText());
        pt.executeUpdate();
          flag=0;}
        if(rs.getString(1).equals(saurabh.getText())){
        pt.setString(2, (String) daalec.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(3,(String)daacomm.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(4,(String)daakno.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(5, (String) daabeh.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(6, (String) daanot.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(7, (String) daapun.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(8,daatext.getText());
        pt.executeUpdate();
          flag=0;}
        if(rs.getString(1).equals(gayatri.getText())){
        pt.setString(2, (String) ecolec.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(3,(String)ecocomm.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(4,(String)ecokno.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(5, (String) ecobeh.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(6, (String) econot.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(7, (String) ecopun.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(8,ecotext.getText());
        pt.executeUpdate();
          flag=0;}
         if(rs.getString(1).equals(tasleem.getText())){
        pt.setString(2, (String) clec.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(3,(String)ccomm.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(4,(String)cknow.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(5, (String) cbeh.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(6, (String) cnote.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(7, (String) cpun.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(8,ctext.getText());
        pt.executeUpdate();
          flag=0;}
         if(rs.getString(1).equals(saurabhs.getText())){
        pt.setString(2, (String)graplec.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(3,(String)grapcomm.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(4,(String)grapknow.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(5, (String) grapbeh.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(6, (String) grapnot.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(7, (String) grappun.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(8,graphtext.getText());
        pt.executeUpdate();
          flag=0;}
         if(rs.getString(1).equals(sanjay.getText())){
        pt.setString(2, (String) softlec.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(3,(String)  softcomm.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(4,(String)  softknow.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(5, (String) softbeh.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(6, (String) softnot.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(7, (String) softpun.getSelectedItem());
        pt.setString(8,softtext.getText());
        pt.executeUpdate();
         flag=0; 
        }
        if(flag==0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Feedback Submitted Successfully");
        }
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }                                   
}
```

This is the code that i am using please help me..
I am trying to execute the code i have given but it keeps giving me the error "At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized." So please Help ...

Comment: `pt.setString(1, ....)` never happens in your code

Comment: Please help get me the solution ..??

Comment: You already have an answer to you question below. You cannot execute a statement before setting the values as James_D explained.

Comment: @SankalpSrivastava I've added an answer, which should work for you.

Comment: Why is this tagged javafx when it is swing/awt code using `JOptionPane` and `java.awt.event.ActionEvent`.  I suggest you remove the javafx tag or, if you really are mixing Swing and JavaFX code in an application, that you stop doing that, as that is not advised in most cases => stick to a single UI framework, either JavaFX or Swing, don't mix them unless you know what you are doing and you know there is no alternative to doing that (which I don't currently see in the context of this question).  Note that this comment is unrelated to solving the question, but just advice on the code presented.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL in your prepared statement has parameter markers:

```
    String query = "INSERT into FACULTY_DETAILS (FACULTYNAME,LECTUREQUALITY,COMSKILLS,KNOWLEDGE,BEHAVIOUR,NOTESPROVIDED,PUNCTUALITY,SUGGESTION) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

These parameters need to be set before you can execute the SQL (it simply doesn't make sense without values in place of the `?`).

However, you are trying to execute the statement without setting the parameters:

```
    PreparedStatement pt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    pt.executeUpdate();
```

which results in the error you describe. It's not really clear what you intend to do by executing the statement at this point.

Additionally, you are trying to use the same statement object both for your query and for your update. I don't believe this will work. Create a separate statement for the query:

```
PreparedStatement queryStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM LOGIN_USER.FACULTY_DETAILS");
ResultSet rs = queryStatement.executeQuery();
```

Finally, note that the subsequent calls to `pt.executeUpdate()`, in the `if` blocks, also occur without all the parameters being set, since you never set parameter number 1 in any of these cases. You will also need to set that parameter to an appropriate value.

Comment: actually what i want to perform is that i want to check if the label name that as same in the name in database then insert the following .So what should i do should i  execute query later..

Comment: @SankalpSrivastava You already do execute the "query" (which isn't a query, it's an insert) later. I have no clue why you are also trying to execute it before you have the information you need.

Comment: Ok please help me provide me the write code or a clue

Comment: @SankalpSrivastava What is wrong with the answer I have provided?

Comment: Now i had firstly inserted value after that had executeQuery but it is giving me error:executeQuery(String)' not allowed on prepared statement

Comment: @SankalpSrivastava See the other answer; you also need a separate statement for the query. (Basically, there are multiple problems with your code.)

Comment: @SankalpSrivastava I've added an answer which should work for you.

Comment: @Sridhar Except you removed the part that I was missing, so your answer is now essentially equivalent to this one.

Comment: @James_D I thought we can't run a new query in prepared statement. Actually we can using the String parameterized methods. Just, found that :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you're preparing a statement which you will use in future, after setting the details you require. 
Then you're trying to execute a `executeUpdate()` which will expect the values to be set.

***Solution: Remove the `executeUpdate()` used before getting the `ResultSet` and setting values for `PreparedStatement`.***

```
 private void SubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  Connection connection;
  PreparedStatement pt;
  Statement st;
  ResultSet rs;
  try {
   int flag = 1;
   try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Error" + ex);
   }
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/loginDB", "login_user", "root");
   String query = "INSERT into FACULTY_DETAILS (FACULTYNAME,LECTUREQUALITY,COMSKILLS,KNOWLEDGE,BEHAVIOUR,NOTESPROVIDED,PUNCTUALITY,SUGGESTION) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
   pt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
   st = connection.createStatement();
   rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM LOGIN_USER.FACULTY_DETAILS");
   while (rs.next()) {
    if (rs.getString(1).equals(kapil.getText())) {
     pt.setString(2, (String) javalec.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(3, (String) javacomm.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(4, (String) javaknow.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(5, (String) javabeh.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(6, (String) javanot.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(7, (String) javapun.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(8, javatext.getText());
     pt.executeUpdate();
     flag = 0;
    } else if (rs.getString(1).equals(ziaul.getText())) {
     pt.setString(2, (String) oslec.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(3, (String) oscomm.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(4, (String) osknow.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(5, (String) osbeha.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(6, (String) osnote.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(7, (String) ospun.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(8, ostext.getText());
     pt.executeUpdate();
     flag = 0;
    } else if (rs.getString(1).equals(saurabh.getText())) {
     pt.setString(2, (String) daalec.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(3, (String) daacomm.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(4, (String) daakno.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(5, (String) daabeh.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(6, (String) daanot.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(7, (String) daapun.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(8, daatext.getText());
     pt.executeUpdate();
     flag = 0;
    } else if (rs.getString(1).equals(gayatri.getText())) {
     pt.setString(2, (String) ecolec.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(3, (String) ecocomm.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(4, (String) ecokno.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(5, (String) ecobeh.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(6, (String) econot.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(7, (String) ecopun.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(8, ecotext.getText());
     pt.executeUpdate();
     flag = 0;
    } else if (rs.getString(1).equals(tasleem.getText())) {
     pt.setString(2, (String) clec.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(3, (String) ccomm.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(4, (String) cknow.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(5, (String) cbeh.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(6, (String) cnote.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(7, (String) cpun.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(8, ctext.getText());
     pt.executeUpdate();
     flag = 0;
    } else if (rs.getString(1).equals(saurabhs.getText())) {
     pt.setString(2, (String) graplec.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(3, (String) grapcomm.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(4, (String) grapknow.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(5, (String) grapbeh.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(6, (String) grapnot.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(7, (String) grappun.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(8, graphtext.getText());
     pt.executeUpdate();
     flag = 0;
    } else if (rs.getString(1).equals(sanjay.getText())) {
     pt.setString(2, (String) softlec.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(3, (String) softcomm.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(4, (String) softknow.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(5, (String) softbeh.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(6, (String) softnot.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(7, (String) softpun.getSelectedItem());
     pt.setString(8, softtext.getText());
     pt.executeUpdate();
     flag = 0;
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Feedback Submitted Successfully");
    }
   }

  } catch (SQLException ex) {
   Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } finally {
   if (rs != null) {
    rs.close();
   }
   if (st != null) {
    st.close();
   }
   if (pt != null) {
    pt.close();
   }
   if (connection != null) {
    connection.close();
   }
  }
 }
```

***Note: I used `else if` in places of `if` to avoid duplicate condition checks. And, finally block to avoid memory leak***

Comment: After executing your code i am getting the following error :Method 'executeQuery(String)' not allowed on prepared statement.

Comment: @SankalpSrivastava Wierd! I've tried the same code and it worked for me. No problem! just create a statement to execute the query for you. I've updated the answer in code for the same.